# how to assign values to list in one column in csv file from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tokens in column 1 in a csv file as shown:

```
subject               rate  
['a','b','c']        0.11  
['a','d','c']        0.3  
['c','e']            0.07  
['f','g','h','i']    0.18
```

Here's the code that has resulted in the above format:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('prom_sub.csv', 'r'))
writer = csv.writer(open('prom_token.csv', 'w', newline = ''))
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for  row in reader:
    s = row[0]
    r = row[1]
    rm_dig = str.maketrans('','', digits)                                   
    s = s.translate(rm_dig)
    tr = str.maketrans('','', string.punctuation)
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s.lower().translate(tr))
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
writer.writerow([filtered_sentence, r])
```

Now, i want to assign the values in column 2 to each token in column 1. That is, here's how I want the out:

```
subject         rate  
a               0.11  
b               0.11  
c               0.11  
a               0.3  
d               0.3  
c               0.3  
c               0.07  
e               0.07  
f               0.18  
g               0.18  
h               0.18
i               0.18
```

I tried to get the column 1 in the required format using a simple for loop. Is there any other way to do this using python?
I want the above mentioned format from prom_token.csv in another csv file. Thanks.

Comment: what did you do till now ? where is your code ?

Comment: First file is not shown in csv format. And second file is not either. What do you want to do exactly, convert the source file (prom_sub.csv) to last format (almost already done) or convert the top file (prom_token.csv) to last format.

Comment: I want to convert the file 'prom_token.csv' that is in the first format to another csv file in the second format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intermediary format is hard to process. First field is the Python representation of a list of strings, which is not a standard format. You should avoid that if you can.

Assuming you have no choice but that format, the only reliable way to parse it is `literal_eval` in `ast` module that will give you back the original list of strings even in corner cases. So your transformation script could be like:

```
with open('prom_token.csv') as fdin, open('outfile.csv', 'w', endline='') as fdout:
    reader = csv.reader(fdin)
    writer = csr.writer(fdout)
    for row in reader:
        for elt in ast.literal_eval(row[0]):   # split the Python representation of a list
            writer.writeline(elt, row[1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm :D